# How to make a curved edge container in css

Tags: css

Is it possible to create those "curved edge text containers" from css without setting any image as background ? Can anyone give me an example or point me to some website that uses something similar?

Thanks !

[image]

Comment: You should at least share some code of an attempt to achieve the desired output.

Comment: these guys use svgs: http://css-tricks.com/

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS3's [border-radius](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_borders.asp) property to add rounded corners.

```
div {
  border: 2px solid;
  border-radius: 25px;
}
```

For more advanced shapes you will need to use CSS's [2d transformations](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_2dtransforms.asp).

The picture above can likely with a combination of border-radius, skew, and background-image.